# query() with Angular $resources, "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I am experimenting with Angular. I created the following module.

```
var archiveModule = angular.module('archiveModule', ['ngResource']);

archiveModule.factory('Archive', ['$resource',
    function($resource) {
        return $resource('/data/archive/:doc.json', {}, {
            query: { method:'GET', params:{ doc: undefined }, isArray:true }
        });
    }]);

archiveModule.controller('ArchiveControl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Archive',
    function ($scope, Archive) {
        $scope.items = Archive.query();
        $scope.orderProp = 'name';
    }]);
```

My template everything happens within:

```
<div class="container" ng-app="archiveModule">
    <div ng-controller="ArchiveControl">
```

I include the angular scripts at the bottom of my page:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-resource.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.12/angular-route.js"></script>
```

And Chrome reports `TypeError: undefined is not a function`, and it goes back to the line `$scope.items = Archive.query();`.

According to http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource.$resource, query is part of $resource and I modeled my resource off http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_11 I'm not sure what's going wrong here.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your parameters don't line up with the dependencies that are declared. It's injecting `$http` into `Archive`...

```
archiveModule.controller('ArchiveControl', ['$scope', '$http', 'Archive',
    function ($scope, Archive) {
```

Remove `'$http'` and it should work...

```
archiveModule.controller('ArchiveControl', ['$scope', 'Archive',
    function ($scope, Archive) {
        $scope.items = Archive.query();
        $scope.orderProp = 'name';
    }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for that! that was it, by the way, why would that prevent it from working? Is it shadowing `Archive` or something?

Comment: Angular looks at the parameter names to determine what dependencies to inject. This works great... until the script is run through a minifier and the parameter names get all mangled. So they allow dependencies to be declared in an array like above. When this happens, it ignores the parameter names and goes strictly by the string names in the array. The downside is that it's easy to get out of sync, as you sort of found out here.  :)